# Generate Doctrine entity getters/setters for a reusable Symfony bundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit

I'm creating a Symfony bundle in isolation, outside of any Symfony installation, to be used across several of my projects. I'm new to this type of workflow in Symfony and I'm a bit confused about how to best approach it.

I know I can write unit tests in order to test the functional side of the bundle, but I've also mapped out about 25 Doctrine entities that I would rather not have to manually define the getters/setters for.

I assumed I'd be able to install the Composer dependancies and then use  `vendor/bin/doctrine` to generate them, but Doctrine throws an error, saying I should define a `config-cli.php` file, which is intended to instantiate an entity manager, which requires a connection.

That's fine, but given there is no actual database (in theory), I don't want to define a connection. I just want to generate the entities and test my services with PHPUnit, and then load the bundle into an actual Symfony installation later.

Am I going about this wrong? An article explaining the workflow would be very helpful, but I'm not finding anything through Google.

Comment: If you use an IDE, it usually is a much better idea to have the getters and setters generated by the IDE, even within a Symfony application.

Comment: I don't use an IDE, just Sublime Text 3. Do you know of any IDEs that support parsing the Doctrine annotations to generate the getters and setters?

Answer (score 0):

Generation of getters and setters is a common feature of IDEs. You can use the free NetBeans IDE, while some might prefer to dish out some money for PhpStorm. Both IDEs can generate the getters and setters for you.

Comment: These are generated from [Doctrine annotations](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html) though, not standard docblocks. I don't know of any IDEs with support for that?

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that it's not possible to run the `generate:*` commands without an instance of the entity manager, not even just to generate the getters/setters. Unfortunately that means a connection is required, which is what I'm trying to avoid for this stage of the development.

I've been looking through some of the more popular Symfony bundles out there, trying to figure out how they handle it. From what I can gather the pattern is to define a base, non vendor-specific model in the `Model/` namespace using standard DocBlocks for the properties (which any ol' generator can be used to parse and generate the getters/setters for,) then to extend the class in a Doctrine specific entity within the `Entity/` namespace.

As `Entity\Foo` extends `Model\Foo`, the type hinting would still be valid, and you only need overwrite the property annotations and any methods requiring Doctrine specific code.

Although it's a little more work initially (ignoring the generation process,) I actually like this approach. Not only does it keep the repetitive getter/setter boilerplate code separate from the Doctrine mappings, but it actually follows best practises by de-coupling the models from Doctrine altogether.